# Determining mailbox type

Tags: email, mail-server, mailbox

I now have a shared server which I use for email. At the moment, I'm configuring a new VPS and I'd like to be able to copy the email from the shared server to the VPS. I'm setting up Postfix using [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix) and have to choose whether I will use mbox or Maildir. I don't know what to choose here.

The mail directory on my shared server looks like this:

- mail

  - .Drafts
  - .Junk
  - .Sent
  - .spam
  - .Trash
  - archive
  - cur
  - new
  - tmp
  - .info@my-domain_com -> mail/my-domain.com/info
  - my-domain.com

    - info

      - (all my directories and .Drafts through tmp of the mail directory)
      - (dovecot files)
  - (dovecot files)

What mailbox type should I use to be able to copy the mails from my shared server to the VPS later on?

---

To me, it looks like Maildir, but different accounts have been placed in one directory (i.e. *not* in the user's home directory but in the domain directory, mail/my-domain.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by using Maildir (not mbox). So I guess it's Maildir then.